# IOS data saving

Tags: ios, database

I would like to create an app where a user can put in some text and save this.
Then i would like to be able that a other user can download this text by putting in the first users email address and his password. say like john@appleseed.com password: 1234.
So if john writes into the iOS app Hi.
And I would "download" this data using the email and pass. 
What is a good way to achieve this?
I've read posts about using an API.
But what is the best way to save data to a data base.
I need to save the

1. Email address of the user
2. Corrosponding Password (randomly generated numbers)
3. List items

the database should look something like this.

[Primary Key: Email adress] [ Password] [Text]

john@appleseed.com          1234    "- Hi 
- Welcome
- To 
- My
- App"
me@icloud.com   3123    "- This
- App
- Works "
you@me.com  546758  "Text
Lorum
Ipsum
doret
samet"

Hope it is clear for you guys!

Comment: sorry.. need more info.. what have you tried? Are you trying to download from the webservice or get the info from sqlite3 database (core data)?

Comment: Hi, was looking at the options of what to use but got confused in the way in. therefor i was asking what the best way is. Say i want you to download what i just typed into my application by having u put in the email and corresponding password.

Comment: use a .php or .aspx web service (preferrably JSON) which gives you a flag to check if the username or password exist OR is valid and then download the user info accordingly.

Comment: So what you are saying is i should create a API in PHP which returns to my app. preferably in json..?
If so could u put that as an answer, so i can mark it as done!

Comment: yes.. make a json web service and parse it in your iOS app and download the data from the web service accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a .php or .aspx web service (preferrably JSON) which gives you a flag to check if the username or password exist OR is valid and then download the user info accordingly. Make a json web service and parse it in your iOS app and download the user info from the web service.

Comment: Ty This solved my question!
For those who have the some problem

Answer (score -2):

Create a database using sqlite or core data with the field names as you required like email-id,password etc. If first user enters some data it should  be saved in db. when second user uses the same user id and password he will get the same data what was stored in db.